# Calling a MySql routine/stored procedure with an EJB Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ejb, entitymanager

After a lot of troubles, my webapp is close to its final version, but it still needs something.

So I need to use a "complex" query to fetch some results.

This query needs to call a MySql routine and has to return a `Map` instead of a `List`.

Here's the query :

```
SELECT d.id, contaOccorrenze(d.descrizione, '" + query + "') AS 'occorrenze' FROM Dispensa d WHERE d.tag LIKE '%" + query + "%' OR d.titolo LIKE '%" + query + "%' OR d.descrizione LIKE '%" + query + "%'
```

where `query` is the word that I'm looking for and `contaOccorrenze` is the routine that I need to call.

This query works fine in Workbench, so the query is not my problem.

Here's the Stack Trace that comes after I try to execute the query :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT d.id, contaOccorrenze(d.descrizione, 'lunga') AS 'occorrenze' FROM Dispensa d WHERE d.tag LIKE '%lunga%' OR d.titolo LIKE '%lunga%' OR d.descrizione LIKE '%lunga%'], line 1, column 28: unexpected token [(].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(83@[()* loopback of 383:9: (d= DOT right= attribute )*])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1477)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:436)
    at facade.DispensaFacade.findLikeComplex(DispensaFacade.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT d.id, contaOccorrenze(d.descrizione, 'lunga') AS 'occorrenze' FROM Dispensa d WHERE d.tag LIKE '%lunga%' OR d.titolo LIKE '%lunga%' OR d.descrizione LIKE '%lunga%'], line 1, column 28: unexpected token [(].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(83@[()* loopback of 383:9: (d= DOT right= attribute )*])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.unexpectedToken(JPQLException.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.handleRecognitionException(JPQLParser.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.addError(JPQLParser.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.reportError(JPQLParser.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.pathExprOrVariableAccess(JPQLParser.java:1436)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.arithmeticPrimary(JPQLParser.java:4720)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.arithmeticFactor(JPQLParser.java:4660)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.arithmeticTerm(JPQLParser.java:4546)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.simpleArithmeticExpression(JPQLParser.java:4462)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.scalarExpression(JPQLParser.java:4834)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectExpression(JPQLParser.java:1269)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectItem(JPQLParser.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectClause(JPQLParser.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectStatement(JPQLParser.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.document(JPQLParser.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.buildParseTree(JPQLParser.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1475)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: NoViableAltException(83@[()* loopback of 383:9: (d= DOT right= attribute )*])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.pathExprOrVariableAccess(JPQLParser.java:1408)
    ... 117 more
```

Here's the full method that I'm trying to use (casting the result `List` to a `HashMap` is a way that I found googling, but I'm quite sure that there's a better way to get a `HashMap` from my query)

```
public HashMap<Integer, Integer> findLikeComplex(String query) {
        String SQLquery = "SELECT d.id, contaOccorrenze(d.descrizione, '" + query + "') AS 'occorrenze' FROM Dispensa d WHERE d.tag LIKE '%" + query + "%' OR d.titolo LIKE '%" + query + "%' OR d.descrizione LIKE '%" + query + "%'";
        return (HashMap<Integer, Integer>) getEntityManager().createQuery(SQLquery).getResultList();        
    }
```

I was also thinking to change my `HashMap` from `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` to `HashMap<Dispensa, Integer>`, by changing the `d.id` statement of the query to `*`.

Will it work or I'm asking too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with  `getEntityManager().createNativeQuery()`

Comment: It works.
I mean, it does the query, but it throws an exception saying that `Vector` cannot be cast to `HashMap` (that's quite obvious).
How can I make this query return a `Map` instead of a `List` ?

Comment: Afaik you can't. So you have to loop through the results and add them to your map..

Comment: Solved. `getResultList()` returns a `List<Object[]>` in this case :)